# Azure Blobs not being created from ASP.Net Form

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm trying to upload image files (JPG) to Azure Blob Storage. I'm using the following code

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials(name, key);
CloudStorageAccount cso = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = cso.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");
string photoName = e_name + e_cr;
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(photoName);
blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(img.OpenReadStream());
```

My issue is that the code is not actually creating the blobs in my container. I've ran it multiple times (once last night and about three to four times today) and the attempt from last night succeeded, however it no longer works. I've tried both Blob and Container access types for my container, so I don't think it's that. img is a IFormFile, and name, key, photoName, e_name, and e_cr are all strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason for blobs not being created could be that you're trying to create blobs asynchronously

```
blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(img.OpenReadStream());
```

However you're not waiting for this async operation to finish. Please change the above line of code to:

```
await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(img.OpenReadStream());
```

and that should make the difference. Please note that the method in which you're calling this code (I am assuming it is a controller action) should also be declared as async.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, few things to focus here

- update the container name to "containername" as the name should contain on lowercase letters.
- add below line after line #4 - this is not required if containername is already created in the storage.

  await extractcontainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
- check the name restrictions for container and blob [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata) and make sure photoName value respects the restrictions.
- Make the change suggested by Gaurav Mantri above.